# Writing a csv file with commas and double quotes in a cell in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to support double quotes and commas in a cell when righting a csv file in Python. heres my code for writing the csv file.

```
def writecsv(filename):
    if(re.match('.csv$', filename)):
    filename = re.sub('\w+', filename)

    try:
        csvfile = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in spreadsheet[3]:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
            csvfile.close()
    except:
        print('The file "'+filename+'" did not save correctly please try again')
```

right now if there is a double quote it ends the cell so how would I skip one of the ending double quotes? each cell is contained in a list.

Comment: What is `spreadsheet`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for the CSV library https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html , it looks like you need to define a dialect object, which allows you to define how quotes should be handled, and pass this to the CSV writer.